# Ranking a Group By result set

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I would like to have a column showing the rank (highest amount being #1) of this result set. Can this be done somehow?
Here is the query to produce [this result](https://wkevin.com):

```
SELECT user_names.user_name,city.city,state.state,SUM(events_full.amount) AS total
FROM user_names,city,state,events_full
WHERE user_names.user_id=events_full.user_id 
AND city.city_id=events_full.city_id 
AND state.state_id=events_full.state_id 
AND events_full.season_id=13
AND amount > 0
Group By user_names.user_name
```

Comment: What type of SQL are you using?  Oracle/SQL Server/My SQL etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a hunch that you actually use MariaDB.
(based on your comment in a deleted answer)

Then you could try to add a [DENSE_RANK](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dense_rank/) over the `SUM` to your `SELECT`

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(events_full.amount) DESC) AS Ranking
```

**A simplyfied example:**

> ```
> create table test 
> (
>   col1 int,
>   col2 int
> );
>
> insert into test values
> (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),
> (2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),
> (3,1),(3,5),
> (4,1),(4,2);
> ```

> ```
> select col1
> , sum(col2) tot
> , dense_rank() over (order by sum(col2) desc) rnk
> from test
> group by col1
> order by rnk
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | tot | rnk
> ---: | --: | --:
>    2 |  10 |   1
>    1 |   6 |   2
>    3 |   6 |   2
>    4 |   3 |   3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e438a1f677518cfc3b0bf0454e79ec1a)*

In MySql 5.7 it can be emulated via variables

**For example:**

> ```
> select *
> from
> (
>   select col1, total
>   , case 
>     when total = @prev_tot 
>      and @prev_tot := total
>     then @rnk
>     when @prev_tot := total
>     then @rnk := @rnk + 1
>     end as rnk
>   from
>   (
>     select col1
>     , sum(col2) as total
>     from test
>     group by col1
>     order by total desc
>   ) q1
>   cross join (select @rnk:=0, @prev_tot:=0) v
> ) q2
> order by rnk;
> ```
>
> ```
> col1 | total | rnk
> ---: | ----: | :--
>    2 |    10 | 1  
>    1 |     6 | 2  
>    3 |     6 | 2  
>    4 |     3 | 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f0b8071228040eb129cab05fcdfc21a7)*

Comment: It's a MySql server when I try it via my webhost. My computer at work says MariaDB. Either way (and I have tried both suggestions I have seen here so far), I get the following:

An alias was previously found. (near "rank" at position 181)
An alias was expected. (near " " at position 180)
Unexpected token. (near "rank" at position 181)

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by SUM(events_full.amount) desc) as rank
FROM user_names
  JOIN events_' at line 5

Comment: Well, `RANK` is also a function.  So it might be a reserved word. What if you quote it, or use name like `degreeofawesome` ?  Well, if it's a MySql 5.7, then it wouldn't know those functions yet.

Comment: No luck. Thanks anyway!

3 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "`degreeofawesome`" at position 181)
An alias was expected. (near " " at position 180)
Unexpected token. (near "`degreeofawesome`" at position 181)
SQL query: Documentation

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by SUM(events_full.amount) desc) as "degreeofawesome"
FROM user_names
' at line 5

Comment: Could you run a `select @@version`.  I noticed anyway that MySql 8.0 does have a problem with the name `rank`. Test [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77595a73f5b57dd2d3c866cfe4fee818)*.

Comment: @Kevin Does the second example run?

Comment: I have not tried it yet. I'm busy with other things right now. To be honest, this is way beyond my level of SQL knowledge. I don't know how to write your second example for use in my situation. I'll study it as much as I can, when I get a chance. Thanks so much though.